# How to get thumbnails for Hi10p videos?

Tags: video, thumbnails

Does anybody know how get thumbnails for Hi10p videos?

I've tried installing the most recent versions of VLC and ffmpeg but neither work for this purpose.

---

**Solution**

I managed to find the answers in a german forum!

In */usr/share/thumbnailers/totem.thumbnailer* I replaced:

```
TryExec=/usr/bin/totem-video-thumbnailer
Exec=/usr/bin/totem-video-thumbnailer -s %s %u %o
```

For:

```
TryExec=/usr/bin/ffmpegthumbnailer
Exec=/usr/bin/ffmpegthumbnailer -s %s -i %i -o %o -c png -f -t 10
```

Answer (score 1):

**Could you add more information**

Could you add ?

- a sample file
- how you are trying to make the thumbnail

**At here**

Looking Hi10P samples:

- http://android.tnonline.net/Software/Video/Hi10P%20Software/
- http://haruhichan.com/wpblog/index.php/205/hi10p-info-guide.html

Downloading:

- hotd-op-1080p-hi10p.mkv
- [DHR-Raws][Osaka_Okan][03][AVC_Hi10P_AAC].mkv
- pussinboots-tlr1_h1080p.mp4

The KDE 4.8 ffmpegthumbnailer is making the thumbnails without problems

[image]

The ffmpegthumbnailer /1/ is making thumbnails

[image]

The VLC is playing and taking snapshots from the clips

[image]

```
:~$ vlc -v
VLC media player 2.0.5 Twoflower (revision 2.0.5-0-g1661b7d)
```

The screengen /2/ is making screenlist from the clips

[image]

Links

1. http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/ffmpegthumbnailer
2. http://qt-apps.org/content/show.php/ScreenGen+-+Screenlist+generator?content=153485

Comment: Thank you for answering. I had ffmpegthumbnailer installed too. But this is what I get with Hi10p videos: i47.tinypic.com/2dre3j6.png. Is the same file you were using as an example (hotd-op-1080p-hi10p.mkv). Instead of the thumbnail, there is an orange icon. But I think it only happens with **mkv** Hi10p videos, because pussinboots-tlr1_h1080p.mp4 gets a thumbnail.